# Python re string parsing

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm trying to use re patterns within scrapy to parse a string. The string is of the format below. I am trying to retrieve the numbers within the font tags (e.g. `08:00`). Easy enough to do in one list `(\d+:\d+)+` but I need two separate lists of `AM` and `PM`. Can you only do this by creating two substrings - `AM` and `PM` - and then running the pattern against each of the substrings? The `(AM -` and `(PM -` are unique. It feels like you should be able to do it directly but I'm out of ideas. Thanks.

example input:

```
(AM – 07:00 <font color=#0002fe>08:00</font> <font color=#0000dd>09:00</font> <font color=#0001fe>10:100</font>) <br> (PM – 18:00 <font color=#0000fe>190:00</font> <font color=#0000fe>175:00</font>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough in my original post. The string provided is a sample but is part of a larger string that contains many other tags inc. <br> tags so splitting on tags in the way suggested isn't an option. Regarding BeautifulSoup, I haven't used it so I think it may be just easier, for me, to use re to extract the two sections into substrings and parse them as indicated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I would first eliminate the HTML tags and get the plain text to work with. For that, you can use an HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '(AM – 07:00 <font color=#0002fe>08:00</font> <font color=#0000dd>09:00</font> <font color=#0001fe>10:100</font>) <br> (PM – 18:00 <font color=#0000fe>190:00</font> <font color=#0000fe>175:00</font>)'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> data = soup.get_text()
>>> AM, PM = data.split("  ")
>>> AM
u'(AM \u2013 07:00 08:00 09:00 10:100)'
>>> PM
u'(PM \u2013 18:00 190:00 175:00)'
```

Comment: Rather than calling `get_text()` on the whole input, why not split on the `<br>` tag itself?

Comment: @dimo414 that's a good point. I am just afraid to overcomplicate the problem for the OP and decided to just show the starting point to make the data more convenient for the task..thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always going to look like the example then you can do this using the following regex:

```
import re
capture = re.compile("(?<=>)[\d:]*(?=<)")
res = capture.findall("(AM – 07:00 <font color=#0002fe>08:00</font> <font color=#0000dd>09:00</font> <font color=#0001fe>10:100</font>) <br> (PM – 18:00 <font color=#0000fe>190:00</font> <font color=#0000fe>175:00</font>)")
for match in res:
    print(match)
```

This won't work if you have other types of tags in there though, as it just finds everything between `>` and `<` with no spaces.

Result:

```
08:00
09:00
10:100
190:00
175:00
```